# Android MediaPlayer Seekbar not changing only tracking

Tags: android, seekbar, runnable, oncreate

I've got it set up with a random sound playing onCreate and I have to add a seekbar to track the audio, it moves with track but will not go back if seekbar is pulled back to another part in the audio. Any help would be great, only beginner, sorry for being a noob :).

```
 public class player1 extends Activity implements Runnable {


private  MediaPlayer mp;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0; 
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private ImageButton playicon;
private ImageButton pauseicon;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;  //*****REPLACE THIS WITH THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SOUND FILES YOU HAVE*****
private SeekBar seek;
private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_1);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        pauseicon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        mfile[0] = R.raw.sound01;  //****REPLACE THESE WITH THE PROPER NAMES OF YOUR SOUND FILES
        mfile[1] = R.raw.sound02;  //PLACE THE SOUND FILES IN THE /res/raw/ FOLDER IN YOUR PROJECT*****
        mfile[2] = R.raw.sound03;
        // Listeners
        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */


        try{
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(player1.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
             mp.seekTo(0);
             mp.start(); 
             // set Progress bar values
                songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                songProgressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                new Thread(this).start();


         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (v.getId() == R.id.pauseicon)
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();
          ImageButton pauseicon =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);

          pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
        } else {
            mp.start();

                 ImageButton pauseicon =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);

                 pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);


            }}});
   }


    public void run() {
        int currentPosition= 0;
        int total = mp.getDuration();
        while (mp!=null && currentPosition<total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }            
            songProgressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }



    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        if(fromUser) mp.seekTo(progress);

    }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `run()` method is never called. Instead create a `Handler` object in the main thread (you did already but it is unused), remove the `Thread.sleep()` from the run method but add a call to `postDelayed()` method of the Handler at the end of `run()` (and maybe a condition to call it only while playing).

After starting playback, call run() method once (from main thread). It will then take care about calling itself subsequently with `postDelayed()`.

Comment: Hey, Ive fixed my own problem but now trying to make it so it is scrollable through the track but does not go back when scrolled back, Ive updated the code any help?

Comment: @user2407147 Like you set a OnClickListener for pauseicon you must set a OnSeekBarChangeListener for the SeekBar. By the way: Your solution may fail in other situations because calling of methods of GUI elements (like setProgress()) should be done only in the main thread (for this particular method it works).